# Google Apps Script with forms to check if a doc url is 'shared'

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-forms, google-apps-for-education

Does anyone know "IF" it is possible to use Google Apps Script with a Google form to auto check "IF" a document URL pasted into the form is a "shared" document?

I'm a teacher and I use Google forms to collect student work, but one of the biggest problems I experience is that students regularly submit url's to "unshared" documents for grading. I'd like to reduce/eliminate this by the form checking the entered document url to see if it is 'shared' befor the form is submitted.

Is this possible? If yes, can someone please point me in the right direction?

Here is the form I'm currently using.
http://mrbenrud.com/index.php/2012-09-08-21-09-45/submit-your-work

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cant get a file from its URL, but if you have the doc Id (its in the URL) then this might help

This function will return `true` if there are editors on the given doc id. If you want to check for other types or sharing such as viewers, replace `getEditors()` with `getViewers()` etc.

```
function isShared(docId){
  var editors = DriveApp.getFileById(docId).getEditors()
  if(editors.length > 0){
    return true
  }
  return false 
}
```

`DriveApp.getFileId(docId).getEditors()` will return an array of editors. For more info, I would have a look at the reference guide:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getEditors()

Comment: Aha sounds familiar i saw the question on g+ and answered there. To  check if its shared specifically with the script owner, try to open it inside a try/catch. The doc id can be extracted from the url.